# Opera dev tools reporting JQuery 1.8.0 (min script) error: "Unhandled DOMException: SYNTAX_ERR"

Tags: jquery, opera, domexception

I'm seeing this error "Unhandled DOMException: SYNTAX_ERR" intermittently on my webpage in Opera 12's dragonfly dev tool. Its coming from the minified JQuery script upon page load (the links below have more detailed info). Only happens with the JQuery 1.8.0 release. Happens with both my downloaded copy and also with the GoogleApis hosted version too. The **[Opera forum says it's a JQuery bug](http://my.opera.com/community/forums/topic.dml?id=1513672)** since it's happening in Chrome developer tools too and on the **[JQuery forum it was closed as not an issue](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12422)**.

I read thru the above posts and some others, but was wondering if there's any functional impact to my page on the times when it does load with this error.?.? Doesn't seem like it, but I can't say for sure and I'm also wondering if there's any quick fixes I can apply to prevent it (not related to configuring the browser dev tools from showing/hiding these instances)?

I ask the first question because with two different code paths to follow, seems like the behavior might change depending on if you're using that functionality or not. Disclaimer: I have not read thru that Jquery script, but the forums above say it's this line causing the DOMException and I have no idea what's that for.

```
try {
    matches.call( div, "[test!='']:sizzle" );  <---------- This line
    rbuggyMatches.push( Expr.match.PSEUDO );
} catch ( e ) {}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like this was a bug of developer tools **only**
As the last comment in jQuery's tracker says:

> 12.50 does not stop on handled exception by default anymore.

Just checked on jQuery 1.8.1 / Opera 12.50 (build 1583). Opera 12.50 does not stop on this error. You can check it yourself.